# Mean Square Error value huge then even Actual value in ML model

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

My Machine Learning model predict close values to actual values but produce a huge value of Mean Square error using the  mean_squared_error(Ytest,preds) formula. Can anyone guide me why this problem occur ? where I am doing mistake?

Comment: This cannot be answered without all details, including predictions and true values.

Comment: If the target contains large numbers, it's completely normal. Try to use `MAPE` (Mean Absolute Percentage Error)

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in comments, it depends on your target. Suppose the following model:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, mean_absolute_percentage_error

X, y = make_regression(n_samples=100, n_features=10, n_informative=5, noise=1, random_state=42)
y *= 1_000_000
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = lr.predict(X_test)
```

Output:

```
# MSE
>>> mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)
1040162886544.8763  # a large number

# MAPE
>>> mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_test, y_pred) * 100
1.749190925052093  # but a small error
```

As you can see the mean squared error is very high (1e12) but the mean absolute percentage error is low (1.74%)

Comment: Thank you for your response. clearly my problem is that so its normal to have any value of MSE when MAPE value is right. Am i correct?

Comment: Yes. MAPE is more understandable for humans while MSE can be more difficult to interpret especially for large numbers. However, If you try to predict a temperature, it's better to use MAE (without P) because it's easy to understand my prediction is good at +/- 0.5°C. Remember, you should always keep the metrics that make it easy to explain your result to others, it's the only thing that matters IMHO.